# Is it possible to change the default schema directory in Apollo Kotlin?

Tags: apollo-client, apollo-kotlin

I am trying to use Apollo Kotlin as GraphQL client for GraphQL queries.
Apollo Kotlin requires a schema in your module’s `src/main/graphql` directory.
All our Schemas are present in a separate git repo (say MyGraphQLSchema). To avoid duplication, can **apollo-kotlin** read schemas from a different location or package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`schemaFile` option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/advanced/plugin-configuration#specifying-the-schema-location) can be used for this.